# How do I extract information from a read-only SQL database?

Tags: sql, datagrip

Hi I am looking to extract User id & emails from our database that have only one profile picture in their profile. I am using the command below.

```
SELECT email
FROM auth_user
WHERE profile_picture_1 IS NOT NULL AND
      profile_picture_2 IS NULL;
```

I have read-only access to our database, and when I attempt to use this, it doesn't show the output data anywhere. I am using DataGrip to do this.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read-only access and not being able to see anything seem like two different problems.  How do you enter the query, and what happens after you run it?

Comment: Hi Hamish, do you have any error messages or logs you could share?

Comment: Just SELECT email
FROM auth_user also shows nothing?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Hi Guys, wow didn't expect this quick a response. Managed to find someone nearby to solve this.